# How to apply customization through Visual Studio to the SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio, site

We have an existing SharePoint online site. Now we are required to introduce some changes in functionality. Can we do it through Visual Studio and send the change to SharePoint Online site? Will it work?

Or we have to do the same only through the JQuery or other client side code directly to the site?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of changes you need to introduce. There are several ways to customize a SharePoint Online site and they have different scope of influence:

- Masterpage

For an existing site collection you may need to change the masterpage. Master pages provide the look and feel for **all** of the pages in your site. By changing the styles or content of a master page, you can quickly change the appearance of an entire site. Modifying in VS:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515920/tools-for-design-pages-and-master-pages-in-sharepoint-2013
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231584.aspx

- App

If you are just introducing some functions, maybe packaging them in an [app](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Plan-customizations-solutions-and-apps-for-SharePoint-Online-b7898ebf-69b7-4196-81e3-b04e1a4e7d67?ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU#__i_want_to) and installing as such will be better. You can install an app on one site, some or all, and you can develop it using Visual Studio or [NAPA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220038(v=office.15).aspx)

- Site template

And you can also consider using templates: package the site into a Web Solution Package file (.wsp) and open it in another environment or application such as Visual Studio and further customize it there. Full instruction how to use templates [here](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989)